# Calling a SOAP endpoint with security header in .NET Core

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, soap

**.net core- Call a soap service with wss security header**

In my .net core class library project I have added reference to a WCF sevrvice(using a wsdl file) and now I have reference class generated under Connected Services.
I am able to call the WCF service with a BasicHttpBinding, but the issue is that the server also expect a security element along with the SOAP header

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-"
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>                    
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>==gMg==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-">                    
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-34A069E7A55FECD03D16098926271579">                
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.test.com/Namespace/test_action</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>uuid:XXX</wsa:MessageID>
    </soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

So basically I want the SOAP message to have this kind of security tag attached to the header. Please see above sample SOAP.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by building my custom header:

```
public class SoapSecurityHeader : MessageHeader
    {
        ......
    }
```

We're then adding this to the SOAP header in the BeforeSendReply method, something like this:

```
public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        SoapSecurityHeader head = new SoapSecurityHeader();
        request.Headers.Add(head);
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to apply MessageInspector to the service. If you can't apply MessageInspector to the service, you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779405/angular-cors-preflight-request-causes-400-bad-request-but-postman-request-works/63788173#63788173).

Comment: Thanks Ding for your reply. I tried this and found that I need to call the SOAP service with .net core. For this I just need to add a custom binding and certificate information. But in .net core as you do not have a webconfig, I cannot add a custom binding through code.

Comment: I am getting InvalidSecurity exception while calling the SOAP service with .net core Custom binding.

Comment: Using MessageHeader does not need to use custom binding, the binding of the client must be consistent with the binding of the server. We can add SoapSecurityHeader to the request through IClientMessageInspector.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was to add a security header to the SOAP request. I found, that with configuration in your bindings you can send security header as well. You may not need any extra code for it.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="<certificate thumbprint here >" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExampleService">
          <security 
                    defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"                    
                    requireDerivedKeys="false"
                    messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
                    securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                    includeTimestamp="true"
                    >
            <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:63454/ExampleService.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExampleService"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IExampleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IExampleService" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" >
        <identity>
          <certificateReference findValue="<certificate thumbprint here >" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```